# Magento-How can i override admin module correctly

Tags: magento

**Hi friends:**

I have overrided some modules : "Enterprise/Pci/Model/Observer.php","Mage/Admin/Model/User.php","Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php","Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php".

And configuration as follows(config.xml):

```
`<global>
    <models>
         <Pci>
             <rewrite>
                   <observer>App_Pci_Model_Observer</observer>
             </rewrite>
         </Pci>
    </models>
</global>`
....

`<global>
    <models>
         <Admin>
             <rewrite>
                   <observer>App_Admin_Model_Observer</observer>
                   <session>App_Admin_Model_Session</session>
                   <user>App_Admin_Model_User</user>
             </rewrite>
         </Admin>
    </models>
</global>`
```

but it doesn't work, my code is not run.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What module does this file belong to?

Answer (score 1):

The module names are case-sensitive. Instead of `<Admin>` use `<admin>`. Instead of `<Pci>` use `<enterprise_pci>`.